# Error when trying to visualize geography data with QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I use PostGis, and want to use QGIS to visualize data. But I get error message when trying to show the points in the table.

I create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE poi
(
  id text NOT NULL,
  coord geography(point),
  CONSTRAINT poi_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX poi_coord ON poi USING GIST ( coord );
```

I add data to the table:

```
INSERT INTO poi VALUES ('P01',ST_GeogFromText('POINT(19.034561 47.486079)'));
INSERT INTO poi VALUES ('P02',ST_GeogFromText('POINT(19.030486 47.490477)'));
INSERT INTO poi VALUES ('P03',ST_GeogFromText('POINT(19.030328 47.49059)'));
```

I see the data in the table:

```
"P01";"0101000020E610000091B75CFDD8083340DD2230D637BE4740"
"P02";"0101000020E610000061FC34EECD073340583849F3C7BE4740"
"P03";"0101000020E610000031276893C307334050DF32A7CBBE4740"
```

I try to add the layer in QGIS , but I don't see anything, the log says the following messages :

```
Query: DECLARE qgis_1 BINARY CURSOR FOR SELECT st_asbinary("coord"::geometry,'NDR'),"id"::text FROM "public"."poi" WHERE "coord" && st_makeenvelope(-180,-90,180,90,4326) returned 7 [ERROR:  Antipodal (180 degrees long) edge detected!]

1 cursor states lost.
SQL: DECLARE qgis_1 BINARY CURSOR FOR SELECT st_asbinary("coord"::geometry,'NDR'),"id"::text FROM "public"."poi" WHERE "coord" && st_makeenvelope(-180,-90,180,90,4326)
Result: 7 (ERROR:  Antipodal (180 degrees long) edge detected!)

Query: CLOSE qgis_1 returned 7 [ERROR:  cursor "qgis_1" does not exist]
```

I tried it with QGIS 2.4.0 and with two DB configs:

- PostgreSQL 9.1.7 with PostGIS 1.5.3
- PostgreSQL 9.3.4 with PostGIS 2.1.3

When I use Geometry instead of Geography, it works well.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you getting that error with the sample data you have just shown?

Comment: Yes, only with this 3 rows.

Comment: (Sorry, I just realized that maybe I was ambiguous: so this error message is with this 3 rows, but of course, the problem also occured when I tested with thousands of other rows - it's just a reduced example, but I could reproduce the problem with these data too.)

Comment: Perhaps the same issue as in https://hub.qgis.org/issues/8572

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you must to define geometry and SRC

ALTER TABLE your_squema."your_table" ALTER COLUMN geometry SET DATA TYPE geometry(MULTIPOINT, EPSG code) USING ST_Force2d(ST_Multi(geometry ));